# Как очень быстро найти идентификатор конкретного элемента?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, консоль, opera

Наверняка довольно нубский вопрос, но, есть ли простой способ, через код или с расширением/в каком-то разделе, найти идентификатор конкретного элемента? Вводить в консоль и получать все элементы, а затем перебирать вручную каждый номер, особенно, если их более 400+ очень неудобный процесс. Я так понимаю, я упускаю что-то очевидное и есть более легкий способ?

**Дополнительное пояснение:**

Допустим я знаю, что какой-то нужный мне элемент находится в массиве `document.querySelectorAll('что-либо')`, как мне сразу узнать под каким `[тут_идентификатор]` он находится?

Comment: кто "он" то? Чем он от других элементов отличается? Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Имеется в виду это? Chrome -> правый клик на элементе -> "Просмотреть код" -> В окне Developer Tools правый клик на выделившемся фрагменте -> "Copy" -> "Copy selector"

Comment: массив[i].id...

Comment: @MedvedevDev "он" - конкретный элемент; 
@Yaant нет, не это;
Попробую объяснить так:
Предположим, что при вводе в консоль `document.querySelectorAll('что-либо')` я получу `NodeList(200)`. Я знаю, что мне нужен конкретный элемент из "что-либо" и я могу нажать по элементу вне консоли "Просмотреть код" и увидеть содержимое этого элемента внутри страницы. Но, чтобы получить содержимое этого элемента через команду, мне нужно ввести в консоль `document.querySelectorAll('что-либо')[число]`, как, кроме как вручную рассматривая `NodeList`, я могу узнать число, под которым находится этот элемент?

Comment: @sudy Ну вот приведенная мной последовательность действий и позволяет получить в буфере обмена селектор для конкретного элемента, который далее можно вставить в консоль, и использовать, например, как `document.querySelector('сюда вставить полученный селектор')`. Все равно не то?

Answer (score 1):

Даже после пояснений ничего не понятно, особенно какова область применения ... Ну, что бы не переливать из пустого в порожнее, то кодом опишу ровно то, что вы сами же и написали ... у вас есть n объектов, вы можете их вывести, можете кликнуть по нужному, казалось бы, вы сами описали все что нужно сделать, но ...

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName('block_item');

Object.keys(items).forEach(k => items[k].addEventListener('click', e => console.log(`
  Привет!
  Я элемент номер ${k}.
  Во мне лежит: ${items[k].innerHTML}
`)));
```

```css
.block_item {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.block_item:nth-child(1) { background-color: red; }
.block_item:nth-child(2) { background-color: orange; }
.block_item:nth-child(3) { background-color: yellow; }
.block_item:nth-child(4) { background-color: green; }
.block_item:nth-child(5) { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_item"><span>0</span></div>
  <div class="block_item"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="block_item"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="block_item"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="block_item"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Предлагаю продолжить пояснения к задаче опираясь на данную реализацию, а не на непонятные `document.querySelectorAll('что-либо')`.